# Retaining entered information for next startup?

Tags: java, android, retain

How would I code my android app to remember the values entered by the user between uses?

As an example, say I have an `EditText` "`input1`" and a `spinner` "`input2`" which give results in a `textview` named "`output1`".

Currently when I close and reopen the app, all entered values and calculations are lost and reset.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You have three options. See all [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

In your case, file I/O and a database will be overkill. I recommend using the Preferences API.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQLite or the raw file system.  The [Notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html) shows basic usage of SQLite.

Comment: Having some trouble understanding how it all works... Am I supposed to be treating the entered values as preferences, files, a database, or what?

I'm new to Java so I apologize if this is obvious.

Comment: It's your choice.  As Bahadir suggests, perhaps the easiest and lightest-weight approach is to use preferences.  However, if you are new to Java it might make sense to begin learning Java first.  One place you can start is http://www.javapassion.com/ but there are lots of others.  Next, I would run through the stock Android tutorials, then start your own app.